# Hibernate. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть Maven проект на 2 модуля. Во втором модуле я поставил Hibernate. К первому модулю не подключен Hibernate, но он импортирует класс-сущность из второго модуля. При этом, при компиляции первого модуля возникают исключения:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vladhuk/roshambo/server/models/Account
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3294)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2107)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vladhuk.roshambo.server.models.Account
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 7 more
```

(Account - это тот самый импортируемый класс-сущность). Пробовал подключать Hibernate зависимость и к первому модулю, и добавлять в него hibernate.cfg.xml, но безрезультатно. Проблема как понимаю в том, что первый модуль не распознает класс-сущность, потому как до этого это был обычный класс и все было хорошо.

---

Второй модуль импортировал в первый таким способом:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladhuk</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Показывать еще что-то из pom'а не считаю нужным. Просили еще показать класс Account, но в нем ничего особенного:

```
package com.vladhuk.roshambo.server.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username = "";
    private String password = "";

    public Account() {}

    public Account(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Getters & setters
}
```

Comment: А покажите сам класс Account

Comment: а еще лучше ваш мавеновский пом

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович добавил

Comment: Все, нашел ошибку: при импортировании модуля, я неправильно указал версию.

Answer (score 0):

В хибернейте нужно указывать ту сущность, которую используешь т.е прописывать ее в конфиге.
Добавь зависимость на родительский модуль(она у тебя есть), зайди в конфигурируешь хайбера и пропиши путь к энтете.